# How to create a TFS report in Excel showing tests passed and failed per build from tests results published via mstest.exe

Tags: excel, tfs, mstest, publish

Here's what we'd like to do:

- A build completes successfully in TFS 2012
- Once complete a separate command line process runs tests via vstest.console.exe generating TRX files.
- Once all tests have completed those tests/TRXs are published against the target build that just completed using mstest.exe
- Once complete we are able to see those published results in Team Explorer - Builds - View Builds for the target build.  Under Summary you can see 100 test runs completed for all 100 tests published against it.

At this point we want to open Excel, connect to the TFS Cube and create an Excel report showing a pass/fail pie chart for the target build.

Can someone advise what Cube data to use.  We've already tried a few things without success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to find the target Cube data.  Thank you.

- Filters - ''
- Columns - Outcome, Test Result Executed By
- Rows - Build, Test Run ID, Test Run Title, Test Run State
- Values - Result Count